# Call methods on class in exectuable jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable

I've created a method in a Java class that does some encryption.  This class utilizes methods from some external jar files.  The requestor of this method has asked that I include my class and the external jar files in one jar file.  I am using Eclipse for my IDE. As I understand it, I need to create an executable jar file in Eclipse, in order to package the external jar files in my own jar file.  In my project, I also created a basic class with a main method in my project that simply calls my method mentioned above (to provide a "main class" for the run configuration for the executable jar).  I exported my project to an executable jar file, and verified that it runs (java -jar jar-file-name) in a command prompt window.  I created a second test project in Eclipse, and added my executable jar file to the build path.  I created a simple class in this test project with a main method that calls the method mentioned above (on the class in my executable jar file).  This compiled, so I exported this project to a normal jar file, and tried to run it (with java -classpath executable-jar-file-mentioned-above;test-project-jar-file class-name.  This fails with a NoClassDefFoundError, referencing a class found in one of the external jar files.

What am I missing here?  This is my first experience with an executable jar file.  Is there anything special that needs to be done when calling methods on a class in an executable jar file?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about executable jar files. The only difference is that an executable jar file defines a main class (with a `main()` method) that will be started when you run `java -jar ...`.

A jar file is in fact a plain zip file containing classes, resources and some additional meta-information.
When you run your jar file and get a ClassNotFoundException, this is an issue with you class path. So you are somehow missing classes, you depend on, located in your external lib.

There are two ways to fix your issue:

1. Add the library jar to the class path when you run your runnable jar
2. Repackage your executable jar to contain all the classes from the external library

I don't know what the Eclipse export functions do. But I would recommend taking a look at the exported jar file first using your favorite zip utility.
I would also recommend using a build tool like maven to create your jar. Here is an example how this can be done using the maven assembly plugin: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/